# Python use glob to search for files by extension

Tags: python

This code works, but I feel bad about it. Did I achieve Python Zen or create a terrible monster?
Note: it doesn't have to be super-fast or work on super-huge directory trees.

```
import glob
from typing import List

# Provide pathname without a trailing /
def find_files_with_extension(pathname: str, extension: str) -> List[str]:
    return list({item for sublist in [glob.iglob(s + "**." + extension) for s in glob.iglob(pathname + "/**/", recursive=True)] for item in sublist})
```

Answer (score 4):

A few suggestions:

1. This doesn't need to be a one line function. Writing it on one line makes it much harder to understand and makes finding mistakes more difficult.
2. Use `os.path.join` to assemble your full pathname + wildcard + extension. That way, you don't need to worry about whether or not your pathname is given with or without a trailing `/`
3. If you're going to worry about a trailing `/` in your `pathname`, you should be equally worried about a preceding `.` in your `extension`.
4. `glob.glob` already returns a list with the matching files. I don't see any need for the complicated, nested list comprehensions you're using. Your function should essentially be a wrapper for calling `glob.glob` that simply makes combining the pathname + extension a little easier for the user.

That being said, here's how I might re-write this function:

```
import glob
import os

from typing import List

def find_files_with_extension(path_name: str, extension: str) -> List[str]:
    extension_wildcard = "*"

    if extension[0] != ".": # suggestion #3
        extension_wildcard += "."
    extension_wildcard += extension

    path_name_wildcard = os.path.join(path_name, "**", extension_wildcard) # suggestion #2

    return glob.glob(path_name_wildcard, recursive=True)
```

Comment: The hardest thing about this is you didn't actually test your code! Python uses # for comments not //. But it's better than mine. +1

Comment: Apologies, I wrote and tested it without comments, then added them in before I posted!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which should work fine, using the new, convenient [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
import pathlib


def find_files_with_extension(path_name, extension):
    return list(pathlib.Path(path_name).rglob("*." + extension))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I wonder how many more years it will take for Python teachers to teach pathlib instead of os.path. However, you should not return a list. rglob already returns an iterable.

Comment: @Zababa I don't mind if teachers are slow to adapt, I just wish more people here (and on SO) made use of it!